# How can I find the x and y scale components for pinch and stretch gestures?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using pinch/stretch to resize objects. I was surprised to find that `ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs` has a single `Scale` property. I would like to allow pinching/stretching to increase/decrease the width and height in the same proportion as the stretch's increase in x and y finger positions. In other words, if the stretch is vertical, I would like to make my object taller, but not wider.

If that's not supported, is it possible to determine the starting and ending finger positions of the pinch/stretch gesture?

Comment: Maybe you can check the [`e.Cumulative.Rotation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.manipulationdelta.rotation) of the gesture?

Comment: Can you be more specific, Xiaoy312? I've looked at the documentation, and traced its value changes while I tried resizing, but haven't been able to see anything I could use. But I may be missing something.

Comment: The `Scale` property is a vector; Isn't `Scale.X` and `.Y` what you are looking for? If not, try using `e.ManipulationOrigin` and `e.TotalManipulation.Translation` from `ManipulationCompleted` event.

Comment: Xiaoy312 are you talking about UWP, `ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs` ?. `Delta.Scale` is a float not a vector, according to the doc(and my observation). Is there another `Scale` property that you're thinking of? As for `ManipulationCompleted`,  I am resizing the object as they are pinching, so I can't really wait until the gesture is complete to give them feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the scaleX and scaleY directly for setting the corresponding Scale value in x and y. But you can get the starting and ending finger positions from the `PointerEntered` and `PointerExited` event. You can get the point in these event handler,

```
private void MyImage_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var point= e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as Image).Position;
}

private void MyImage_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as Image).Position;
}
```

But the position value is base on your UIElement left top corner(0,0). So you should set a fixed coordinate. You can try to use the `PointerEntered` and `PointerExited` event of the **Root panel** which includes your resized objects to get the positions of the pinch/stretch gesture.

```
//MyGrid is the root panel and includes the Image which would be resized.
private void MyGrid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("EN>>>"+e.GetCurrentPoint(MyGrid).Position);
}

private void MyGrid_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("ET>>>"+e.GetCurrentPoint(MyGrid).Position);
}
```

Comment: Breeze, thanks very much for your answer. I'm afraid, though, that it has the same problem as Xaioy312's. I am trying to give visual feedback during the pinch/stretch process by resizing the object they are manipulating. The 'PointerExited' event doesn't occur until the whole manipulation is complete, when it's too late. I was looking for the x and y changes during each `ManipulationDelta` event to resize "under their finger" as they pinch/stretch. I've been looking for apps that do this, without success. I'm beginning to wonder if it's possible.

Comment: Currently, you can not get the scaleX and ScaleY when you manipulate the Element, you can submit this feature request to the UserVoice website:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform.

Comment: Thanks, Breeze. I submitted the request as you suggested. It's helpful for me to know that continuing to try is a waste of time. I'd vote for your comment as the answer if I could.